# How to check in a "for" cycle if an object is linked (User

Tags: python, objects

I would like to bypass the linked objects in a "for" loop, but I wouldn't know what condition to use.
I'd write something like this:

```
for o in bpy.context.scene:
    if o is ###"single user":
        print(o.name)
```

Linked object example:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean whether an specific object has more than 1 user?

Comment: @brockmann, Yes, like to, if object have 1 or more copy linked

Comment: `Object.data.users` returns the number of users

Comment: @brockmann ,I think this should be posted as an answer in order to earn points, that's exactly what I was looking for. Ty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Object.data.users`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ID.html#bpy.types.ID.users) returns the number of data-block users. *Proof using the Console:*

```
>>> for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
...     print ("Object name:", ob.name, "- Users:", ob.data.users)

Object name: Cube - Users: 1
Object name: Light - Users: 1
Object name: Camera - Users: 1
```